# posting from java to php and inserting it into mysql database

Tags: java, php, mysql

I write a simple post from java to my php backend.
After I run the script I am getting the output that I am passing in filename, filesize etc..

```
int filesize=25;
String filetype=".txt";
String hash="sdfjksdfhljahe8wr897348957jsdfajlsdhfl48";
String email="sangwan.ritesh@yahoo.in";
String filename="songs.txt";
String urlParameters = "filename="+filename+"&filesize="+filesize+"&filetype="+filetype+"&filehash="+hash+"&email="+email;    
URL url = new URL("myurl");
HttpURLConnection hp=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
hp.setDoInput(true);
hp.setDoOutput(true);
hp.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
hp.setRequestMethod("POST");
hp.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
hp.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
hp.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
hp.setUseCaches (false);
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(hp.getOutputStream ());
wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
wr.flush();
String line;
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(hp.getInputStream()));
line = reader.readLine();
 System.out.println(line);
wr.close();
reader.close();
hp.disconnect();
```

The problem is I want to insert these values into my mysql database running on server so I write the following php code.

```
<?php
include('dbc.php');
$filename=$_POST['filename'];
$filesize=$_POST['filesize'];
$filetype=$_POST['filetype'];
echo $POST['email'];
$filehash=$_POST['filehash'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$query = "INSERT INTO files ( `email`, `file_name`, `file_ext`, `file_size`, 'file_hash') VALUES ( '$email', '$filename', '$filetype', '12584', 'filehash')";
$result=mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
if(mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1)
{
  // DO Nothing
}
 echo $_POST['filehash'];
echo $_POST['email'];
echo $_POST['filename'];
echo $_POST['filesize'];
echo $_POST['filetype'];
?>
```

The data is being is posted and I am getting the same back in my java application but data is not being entered in mysql database. I have a table name files with the same columns described above. I tried to get error from mysql_error but I am not getting any error.

UPDATE:
Problem solved silly sql syntax mistake using ' instead of ` near file_hash

Comment: have you checked your mysql syntax?

Comment: The syntax above is correct and I am not getting any error

Comment: do echo $query and then try to run this query on db, write what happens

Comment: could you post the create statement you used to create the files table?  It could help identity the problem.

Comment: @RobertPodwika
This is the output after do echo $query

INSERT INTO files ( `email`, `file_name`, `file_ext`, `file_size`, 'file_hash') VALUES ( 'sangwan.ritesh@yahoo.in', 'songs.txt', '.txt', '25', 'sdfjksdfhljahe8wr897348957jsdfajlsdhfl48')

error while running this query on server

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''file_hash') VALUES ( 'sangwan.ritesh@yahoo.in', 'songs.txt', '.txt', '25', 'sdf' at line 1

Comment: Yep.. You singlequoted them, instead of backquotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your variables before entering them in the database. Are you sure they are not empty?